# File upload using axios post with basic auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to upload file to server using axios post request.

I'm using the input tag for file and onChange setting the state.

If I use   headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },  in axios the code gives error 400.

And If I remove it the code works fine but sends empty array via POST.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Image extends Component {
  state = {
    image: null
  };

  handleFiles = e => {
    this.setState({ image: e.target.files[0] });
  };

  handleUpload = () => {
    var session_url = "https:/localhost:3000/wp-json/gf/v2/entries/";

    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("image", this.state.image);

    var entries = {
      form_id: "1",
      15: fd
    };

    axios
      .post(session_url, entries, {
        headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },

        withCredentials: true,
        auth: {
          username: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          password: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data });
        console.log(res, "Authenticated");
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error on Authentication", error.message);
      });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFiles} />

        <button onClick={this.handleUpload}>Upload</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Your data is broken

Pass Axios **either** a plain object or a FormData object. It can handle both.

It will not properly serialise a plain object where one of the property values is a FormData object.

```
const entries = new FormData();
fd.append("image", this.state.image);
fd.append("form_id": "1");
```

## Your content type is broken

Do **not** manually set a Content-Type header. It will be generated (including the *mandatory* boundary parameter for multipart requests) from the FormData object.

## Your server-side code might not support this

You need to ensure that your server-side code can handle a multi-part request.